# How to implement a function similar to editing custom labels for contacts in the address book of an Apple mobile phone?

Tags: flutter

How to implement a function similar to editing custom labels for contacts in the address book of an Apple mobile phone, as shown in the figure below
[image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcAaR.jpg)

Please try your best to explain the principle. I am a newbie. The more detailed the better. If you can have the source code on github, that would be even better.
Thank you very very very much!